# Error Visual Studio Code "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?"

Tags: javascript

Al intentar ejecutar código en Visual Studio Code me sale ese problema, presiono F5 para ejecutar el codigo y me sale ese problema. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? o ¿Por qué sucede este error?

Error: **"Cannot find runtime  'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?"**

Estoy usando la última versión de Visual Studio Code y Windows 10.

Comment: instalaste nodejs para todos los usuarios y reiniciaste visual studio code al haberse instalado nodejs?

Comment: Ehm no :v, solo descargue Visual Studio Code y empeze a hacer un archivo en Javascript y cada vez que ejecutó codigo me sale ese error, pero solo me sale con Javascript he probado con Python y no me sale ese error. Se supone que si sigo tu respuesta ¿Llegaré a solucionar mi problema? O ¿Tengo que seguir más pasos?. Al buscar Node.js en Visual Studio Code me sale que ya está instalado, ¿Tengo que instalarlo aparte de Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Python no lo descargue de su web sino de una extensión de Visual Studio Code, pero si instalo Node.js de su web, ¿El problema en Visual Studio Code con Javascript al ejecutarlo se soluciona? Intentaré con tu respuesta, espero que funcione. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Python` requiere instalarse, `javascript` **NO** necesita instalarse para probarlo, ya que `javascript` **puede ser probado por medio de un navegador**, para el caso de `nodejs`, `nodejs` es un tanto distinto de `javascript`... `nodejs` fue construido con **C++** pero usa `javascript` como lenguaje de programación y se considera un **framework del lado del servidor basado en javascript**, el cual puede ser ejecutado mediante una terminal al igual que `python`, por este motivo es necesario aclarar que usar `nodejs` no es exactamente lo mismo que usar `javascript` puro, si solo quieres probar `javascript` en la web solo necesitas un navegador.

Si lo que quieres es usar `nodejs` deberás descargarlo e instalarlo así como hiciste con `python` desde su pagina oficial, te recomiendo la ultima versión estable (LTS). hay que aclarar que la idea de usar `nodejs` es meramente para cuestiones del lado del servidor (nada del lado del cliente ni interfaces graficas), para ello deberás usar `javascript` en navegador **del lado del cliente**, el cual te permitirá interactuar con `HTML` y `CSS`, ademas recuerda que `javascript` viene por defecto en la mayoría de navegadores.

para poder usar `javascript` deberás crear primero un archivo `.html`, y luego en ese archivo referenciar a tu archivo con extension `.js` de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src = "carpeta/script.js"></script>
```

De esta manera al abrir el archivo `.html` con algún navegador el navegador buscara el script y si lo encuentra lo ejecutara.

Para probar si el script esta correctamente referenciado y esta funcionando, puedes intentar en tu `script.js` poner lo siguiente al inicio del codigo:

```
document.write("Hello world!");
```

No es muy recomendable depurar usando esa forma, puesto que ese `script` imprimirá en el documento del **navegador** directamente, lo ideal seria que para depurar la web uses:

```
console.log("The world is ours!");
```

Esto no imprimira nada en la web y no veras nada a simple vista, pero si abres las **opciones de desarrollador del navegador web** con `F12` y te diriges al apartado `consola` veras un mensaje.

La consola es muy útil para revisar errores y depurar.

Comment: por cierto, antes de depronto que pase lo que en algunas ocasiones me pasa, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda y soluciono tu problema y aclaro tus dudas, puedes darle al boton que parece un chulo para dar la respuesta como aceptada ;3

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta :D. Pero si quiero usar Javascript en Visual Studio Code ¿Si o si tengo que usar Node.Js, o tenerlo instalado?

Comment: No puedes usar javascript en visual studio code por que como he dicho antes, javascript corre en un navegador, visual studio code puede correr scripts en la terminal, pero recuerda que python usa una terminal para ejecutarse, javascript requiere es un navegador, si deseas poder ejecutar javascript desde visual studio code no se puede por que visual studio code NO es un IDE, pero en cambio Visual Studio (sin el code) si que lo es y lo permite, pero no hay porque complicarse o llenar de espacio el disco duro descargandolo, ya que siempre puedes probarlo abriendo el archivo .html en el navegador.

Comment: No te recomiendo que instales nodejs para esa causa, porque sospecho que lo que deseas es enrealidad interactuar con elementos HTML y estilos de pagina CSS para crear interfaces graficas y a su vez que la pagina pueda hacer uso de javascript (esto se le conoce como frontend) y es la parte "visual", nodejs seria para lo "no-visual", ya sabes, bases de datos y procesamiento de estas o transporte de informacion.

Comment: Ya tenía Visual Studio descargado jajaja pero me va lento :'c así que prefiero usar Visual Studio Code, ya te entendí, y en el caso que quiera usar Node.js con Javascript ¿Puedo usar Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Por supuesto, pero recuerda, nodejs corre en terminal, mientras que javascript corre en el navegador, los archivos que sean de nodejs o el codigo explicito de nodejs no corre en javascript, pero codigo nativo de javascript debe correr a la perfeccion en nodejs, NO INTENTES MEZCLARLOS, lo digo porque nunca es buena practica tener el frontend (javascript) mezclado con el backend (NodeJS), para comunicarse entre ellos deberas usar peticiones HTTP, tal como POST o GET, las cuales deberas consultar, o incluso en ciertos casos socket.io o websockets estaria bien para otros propositos...

Comment: Sospechaste bien jaja aunque no del todo, solo quería un entorno en dónde ejecutar codigo de Javascript y pensaba que en Visual Studio Code se podía, muchas gracias por tu respuesta realmente me hubiera quedado más tiempo pensando que se podía. :D

Comment: Si solo quieres probar codigo javascript sin tener en cuenta estructura o codificaciones o no tener que abrir el navegador, puedes instalar nodejs, eso esta bien, de hecho si eso es lo que deseas es hasta recomendable usar nodejs, puesto que no necesitaras un navegador para correrlo, solo la terminal de visual studio code, para ello solo debes instalar nodejs para todos los usuarios desde la pagina original y una vez instalado recuerda reiniciar visual studio code para que te reconozca nodejs en la terminal, de esa forma puedes correr un script usando node nombre_script.js

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias :3

Answer (score 0):

al parecer no es un problema de visual studio code, probablemente no tienes el directorio que tiene el binario de node en tu PATH podrias indicar el sistema operativo.

en todo caso puede correr la terminal o CMD(windows) el comando node para verificar esto.

en sistema basado de unix o unix-like como linux puedes modificar un archivo dentro de tu carpeta de usuario: los mas comunes pueden ser **.bashrc** o **.bash_profile**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/la_ruta_a_la_carpeta_que_contiene_el_bin_de_node"
```

en windows usar el comando SET o SETX, por ejemplo

```
 SET PATH=%PATH%;c:/la_ruta_a_la_carpeta_que_contiene_el_bin_de_node
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no te entiendo mucho :'c, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y la verdad no sé a qué te refieres. Estoy usando Windows.

Comment: sabes usar el CMD? si es asi, abrelo y escribe node debera aparecer la consola interactiva de node, o puedes de visual studio code ejecutar desde menu de terminal una terminal de cmd y desde ahi probar.

Comment: Tomaré en cuenta tu respuesta, gracias.

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho y dice: "nose" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. No me soluciona el problema.